# PHP: how to download YouTube videos?

Tags: php, youtube, screen-scraping, web-scraping

I need to be able to directly download certain YouTube videos using PHP. Based on what I have read on the net, it seems like I need the `video_id` and `t` parameters of the Flash vars.

I have written code to grab these values from YouTube. So, for http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YUBbTMdLD0Q, I get the following:

- video_id = YUBbTMdLD0Q
- t = vjVQa1PpcFP86ZrlCWJMcfURrN-0uI5ElVojDbYC4nc%3D

And from my understand, all I need to do next is download the file: http://www.youtube.com/get_video?video_id=YUBbTMdLD0Q&t=vjVQa1PpcFP86ZrlCWJMcfURrN-0uI5ElVojDbYC4nc%3D

This doesn't work. Suggestions?

Comment: Just follow the link. Chrome tell me: "Oops! This link appears to be broken."

Comment: `get_video` is like 400 years old, it doesn't work anymore. It is nowadays against the terms of use to download youtube videos. It can be done but I'm not gonna help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well i did not accept any terms of use so here is a link to script that does what you want in an other language (JavaScript), but I am sure you can figure out how it works. It is MIT license so dont worry for legal terms here ^^

http://userscripts.org/scripts/review/25105